# java.sql.SQLWarning: [StarSQL JDBC Driver][DB2] A CNTQRY or CLSQRY command was issued for a query that is not open

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

on `resultSet.next()` it throws Exception

> java.sql.SQLWarning: [StarSQL JDBC Driver][DB2] A CNTQRY or CLSQRY
>   command was issued for a query that is not open

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()){
///
}
```

Can anybody had faced this issue before, any help is appreciated.

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server or DB2?

Comment: @Jens it is StarSQL

Comment: have you tried the db2 jdbc drivers from ibm?

Comment: @PeterSchuetze thanks, yes!!!  the problem occurred due to driver issues.once I have tried with db2 driver it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above:

> Have you tried the db2 jdbc drivers from ibm? – Peter Schuetze Sep 2
> at 20:41
>
> @PeterSchuetze thanks, yes!!! the problem occurred due to
> driver issues.once I have tried with db2 driver it works fine.. –
> Kanhu Bhol Sep 5 at 5:46